# What is the Azure VM Image URN for Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS?

Tags: server, 20.04, virtualization, lts, azure

We are currently using Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS for our self-hosted Azure VMs and looking into upgrading them to Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. We used the URN `Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-LTS:latest` to create our existing self-hosted Azure VMs.

This webpage link (https://az-vm-image.info/?cmd=--all+--publisher+Canonical) lists the URNs for the various Azure VM images that `az vm image list --output table` command would list from the Azure CLI.

If you collapse groups for that webpage, I would expect a **Canonical - UbuntuServer - 20.04-LTS** or `Canonical:UbuntuServer:20.04-LTS:<version>`to be at the end of that list but it isn't. I know the Azure VM image exist though  because the marketplace has it: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/canonical.0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal?tab=Overview

I'm new to this so I'm not sure how to get the URN out of that marketplace link or which is the correct URN at the az-vm-image link above to get UbuntuServer 20.04 LTS for our self-hosted Azure VMs.

For reference, I am using the Azure CLI command `az vm create .. --image Canonical:UbuntuServer:18.04-LTS:latest ..` to create our VMs. I tried `Canonical:UbuntuServer:20.04-LTS:latest` and the VM image doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a GitHub issue that tells which is the correct URN: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13320#issuecomment-649867249

Looks like the offer and SKU format were changed for 20.04 which is why it could not be found. The correct URN for Ubuntu Server 20.04-LTS is `Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal:20_04-lts:latest`.

Answer (score 0):

In **packer** use :

```
variable "azure_subscription_id" {
  type = string
  default = ""
}
variable "region" {
  default = "Australia East"
}
variable "resource_group_name" {
  default = "my-images"
}

locals { timestamp = regex_replace(timestamp(), "[- TZ:]", "") }
source "azure-arm" "azure-ubuntu" {
  # Ubuntu Base Image
  image_publisher = "Canonical"
  image_offer = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal-daily"
  image_sku = "20_04-daily-lts-gen2"

  # Azure Details
  vm_size = "Standard_B1ls"
  subscription_id = var.azure_subscription_id
  location = var.region
  os_type = "Linux"

  # Managed Image Details
  managed_image_name = "my-image-name-fixme-${local.timestamp}-{{uuid}}"
  managed_image_resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

build {
  sources = ["source.azure-arm.azure-ubuntu"]
  # TODO: Add all your apt-get and shell provisioners and co ...
}
```

Run with : `packer build -var 'azure_subscription_id=FIXME' -var "region=australiasoutheast" -var "resource_group_name=FIXME"`

Comment: Hi why did you choose focal daily and no other choice? What about compatibility?